# How to send message with discord.py bot from another python file?

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

Here are skeleton versions of my code:

**bot.py**

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

async def send_notification(notification):#this method is tested and works when called from same file
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.text_channels:
            if channel.name == CHANNEL_NAME:
                await channel.sent(notification)

def start_bot():
    client.run(TOKEN)

def notification(notification):
    asyncio.create_task(send_notification(notification))#likely error here
```

**main.py**

```
import bot
from time import sleep

def main():
  bot.start_bot()
  sleep(10)
  bot.notification('some notification')

main()
```

Hello, I am trying to send a message to all guilds from a different python file. I understand that I am making some fundamental error with how asynchronous tasks are handled. Currently **main.py** doesn't even get to the *sleep()* statement.

1. Is there some way to reference the *client* from **main.py** so that it would be possible to call methods with it
2. Could I create some api so any python file can access methods inside the bot

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround found. Looking more into the documentation of *discord.py* it is clear that it likes to be it's own self contained thing, which is why my approach of referencing it from other files was not ideal. I ended up continuously reading from a **json** file:

```
async def update_notifications():
    while True:
        with open(JSON_PATH, 'r') as file:# extract all content from json file
            content = json.load(file)
        while len(content['notifications']) > 0:# send all notifications one by one
            await send_notification(content['notifications'][0])
            content['notifications'].pop(0)
        with open(JSON_PATH, 'w') as file:# write the now empty content back to json file
            json.dump(content, file, indent=4)
        await asyncio.sleep(20)# sleep in seconds
```

The json file is structured as such:

```
{
    "notifications":["notification1","notification2",...]
}
```

And to trigger the coroutine `update_notifications()` a loop is created `on_ready`.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    client.loop.create_task(update_notifications())
```

This approach has the advantage that any python script, or even other languages can tell the bot to send a notification by writing to the json file.

Answer (score -1):

`client.run(TOKEN)` blocks execution of the main thread because it starts an async event loop. If you want to just run a task after the bot is started up, you can use the bot's `on_ready` handler:

```py
import discord

client = discord.Client()

CHANNEL_NAME = "some-channel"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        for channel in guild.text_channels:
            if channel.name == CHANNEL_NAME:
                await channel.send("hello world!")

client.run('your token here')
```

See: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html

To answer your 2 questions:

1. `bot.client` should do that, but what you're doing is kind of an anti-pattern when making Discord bots. It's probably best to stick to the documentation. However, you could subclass your bot using inheritance, but that's a bit more advanced.
2. You can already access the bot methods. See above.